# QGIS 3.16 crashes when importing GeoPandas

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopandas

I've recently installed `Pandas` and `GeoPandas` in Ubuntu 18.04 using `pip`.
Unfortunately, when I import GeoPandas in PyQGIS, QGIS 3.16 crashes and closes.

I'm using: Python 3.6, Pandas 0.24.0, Fiona 1.8, GeoPandas 0.9.0

Comment: You've probably broken/upgraded one of QGIS's dependencies like GDAL. Can't tell because you haven't provided any details.  Suggest you delete all your pip installed packages and install via apt if possible.  I'm using  20.04 not 18.04 but geopandas is available in the repos (`sudo apt install python3-geopandas`). If you must install via pip, make sure you install a version that works with your existing system gdal version.

Comment: I removed and re-installed most of the dependencies like GDAL but nothing changed. Then I unistalled QGIS but now I cannot install it again: "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: "*removed and re-installed*" GDAL how?  To fix held broken error `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: `sudo apt install -f` didn't work for me. I removed GDAL at all from my computer and then I installed the lastest version of QGIS 3.18. Then `sudo apt install python3-geopandas`. now QGIS works but when I import GeoPandas an exception appear: 'std::bad_alloc'

Answer (score 1):

On Mac and Windows no problem, but on Debian I found a conflict between packages that crash Qgis. My solution is to set the PYTHONPATH.

Open a terminal and look where is geopandas:

```
pip3 show geopandas
Name: geopandas
Version: 0.8.2
Summary: Geographic pandas extensions
Home-page: http://geopandas.org
Author: GeoPandas contributors
Author-email: kjordahl@alum.mit.edu
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

After that in `Qgis > Settings > System > Environment`, add variable `PYTHONPATH` (`Overwrite`) `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`